# Select different cells each time with CommandButton_click

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for some guidance on creating a single button in excel that performs a different action each time it is clicked. I'm interested in navigating and selecting a different specific cell of the same excel sheet each time the button is clicked. I have gotten how to select a single cell on the first click, but if I'm interested in cycling through, say, 10 different cells all over the sheet, how is it best to do that? I have thought about making a counter and on first click it goes to "c47" on second click it goes to "d59" and so on. I also have the button floating so it moves along with the user interaction.

Below is the code I have so far, but I do not know how to insert a counter to cycle through the next cell selection options per button click. Thank you so much!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Project Brief_Executive Summary").Range("c47").Select

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    On Error GoTo 0
    With Cells(Windows(1).ScrollRow, Windows(1).ScrollColumn)
        CommandButton1.Top = .Top + 100
        CommandButton1.Left = .Left + 1500
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the button on the same sheet as the cells being selected?

Comment: The button is on the same sheet as the cells to be selected, correct.

Answer (score 3):

This will do something like you want.

If one of the cells is already selected, it will select the "next" one.  If none of the cells is selected then it will select the first one.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim arr, addr, m
    arr = Array("A1", "B10", "C30") 'for example: the cells to select
    addr = Selection.Address(False, False)
    m = Application.Match(addr, arr, 0) 'm is 1-based, but arr is zero-based
    If Not IsError(m) Then
        m = m - 1 'fix the base to match the array indexes
        If m = UBound(arr) Then
            addr = arr(0) 'at end, so cycle back to start of array
        Else
            addr = arr(m + 1) 'next address
        End If
    Else
        addr = arr(0) 'start here if no cell already selected   
    End If
    Me.Range(addr).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. When I entered the code and try and click the button, no action occurs. Why would that be?

Comment: I just made a few edits so make sure you have those.  It only does anything if one of the cells is already selected.  If you want it to always do something, have it select the first cell if no cell in the array is already selected.

Comment: Thanks so much!! Could you please add in the portion of the code to select the first option if nothing is selected, that is exactly what I was hoping for! I'm a bit of a beginner to VBA.

Comment: With what it is currently showing as the answer, it is not selecting the cells anymore. It was working, but now it's not... not sure how I messed up the code in excel just now

Comment: Is it not working for mine because the answer is "as long as a cell is selected"? Even when I have one of the cell options selected, it isn't working for me. I'm sorry for so many questions.

Comment: Forgot to update the preamble to the code.  It now describes how it should work.